# Xamarin randomly doesn't recognize names

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I can still build and run my application normally, but it's becoming quite annoying. I will also have issues with things like writing a new method called "FillTexturedTriangle" for my Surface class, and then it won't exist to Xamarin if I'm trying to call it. But it will still build and run normally.

http://puu.sh/n8UGs/b66a435b8d.png

And if I hover over the parameter I will get this message:

http://puu.sh/n8UPE/bd48d49f42.png

Does anyone know why this is? OR where I can view a log to see if there are exceptions...

Comment: have you tried different variablenames? Maybe without numbers? Usually numbers work in c# variablenames. But just to eliminate the possibility of Xamarin doing it wrong.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't make a difference

Comment: I've figured it out. Lines like these cause resolve errors later on in the code: public int Width => Bitmap.Width;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Xamarin does not like lambda operators. This example will cause resolve issues in local names afterwards.

public int Width => Bitmap.Width;